# Displaying default image for users with no profile picture

Tags: php, database

I have this code for showing the profile picture of the user who has logged in:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row_user['profilepic']; ?>">
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

How do I include a `deafultimage.jpg` if the user has no profile picture?

Comment: Will be empty `profilepic` if user has no image?

Comment: yes, it will be empty

Answer (score 3):

Check if `$row_user['profilepic']` is [**empty**](https://www.php.net/empty) and print according

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="images/<?php echo !empty($row_user['profilepic']) ? $row_user['profilepic'] : 'deafultimage.jpg'; ?>">
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```